# mysql selecting last duplicate record with primary key

Tags: php, mysql, csv, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to create a query statement where it joins `Master` and `Query` tables by a column (`PhoneNumber`) and retrieves only the last record of the duplication if it exists

**Master**

```
id      PhoneNumber     Flag    Date    
10009   425729233   N   2013-11-01
10011   425728397   N   2013-11-01
10012   425726253   Y   2013-11-01
10014   425726253   Y   2013-11-01
```

**Query**

```
PhoneNo
425729233
425728397
425726253
433699225
```

**Expected Result:**

```
id      PhoneNumber     Flag    Date
10009   425729233   N   2013-11-01
10011   425728397   N   2013-11-01
10014   425726253   Y   2013-11-01
```

**Tried queries**

```
Select id, PhoneNumber, Flag, Date from Master,Query where Master.PhoneNumber = Query.PhoneNo group by phoneNumber having max(id)

Select id,PhoneNumber, Flag, Date from Master, Query where Master.PhoneNumber = Query.PhoneNo and id in (select max(id) from Master)
```

Any help on how to handle the skipped value `433699225` from query table would be helpful. Basically the query table is an import from csv which compares against the master table and the final output including the matched and the unmatched needs to be exported into a csv.

Comment: Just select `MAX(id)`

Comment: @zerkms your answer will only work if largest id always corresponds to the most recent date.

Comment: @portforwardpodcast You have a point. However, that happens to be exactly what the OP has been doing in the tried queries section. So seems to be a fair solution

Comment: @portforwardpodcast: if OP used `MAX(id)` - it means that it's the deal. So I based my comment on the current query. PS: oops, the same was already mentioned by Mosty Mostacho

Comment: This question is asked EVERY SINGLE DAY in EVERY SINGLE SQL forum. Do we really need to answer it again here?

Comment: A Duplicate of the most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag

Comment: @Strawberry: could you please provide/ point me to the link.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the group by which did the trick,

And Right Join is used to for getting the remaining unmatched values from table2. Where the syntax is like 
 right

```
select Master.id, query.PhoneNo, Master.Flag, Master.Date from (select Master.id, Master.PhoneNumber, Master.Flag, Master.Date from Master where Master.id in (select max(id) from Master group by PhoneNumber)) Master right join query on Master.PhoneNumber = Query.PhoneNo
```

Thanks